# how to get the full sized layer mask like photoshop in LibPSD library

Tags: mask, layer

[Layer Mask image from libpsd Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBc0o.png)
For this first image, It is a layer mask i have retrieved the data from LibPSD library and from that retrieved data  i have created PNG .
[Layer Mask image from photoshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRjWg.png)
and this second image, It is a layer mask this i have got from photoshop.

so here from libpsd library i'll get layer mask not fully, but in the photoshop its full data
so can we get full layer mask data like photoshop.

i have tried retrieving layer mask data from libpsd library and it is not getting full